# How to use open source version of Kendo UI in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I see Telerik provides open source version of Kendo UI at following URL

http://www.telerik.com/download/kendo-ui-core

I downloaded it but not able to make it work in ASP.NET MVC application.

I am not sure what i am missing. I make a call to CSS and JS files as mentioned in below link:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-4

Although I am missing one step **Add reference to Kendo.Mvc.dll** because Telerik don't provide installer in free version and I need JavaScript version of Kendo UI not with MVC selector.

Any idea here?

Comment: If you are looking for the server side widgets that you can use in your razor views then you have to get the paid version. The core ui is javascript only. Also I believe you can install it via nuget in visual studio.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I am looking for JavaScript only. I installed it via Nugget but it is not working. So I am not sure what is missing.

Comment: Did you add the appropriate references? Check this: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/javascript-dependencies

Comment: No Luck so far. Not sure what I am missing. I have done exactly as told above. Also I am trying to use it in MVC 4 application. I checked in view-Source and all the CSS and .JS related to Kendo are loading correctly. Maybe I ll try it again sometime. I have used this control previously but that was in a company with kendo license.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to: http://dojo.telerik.com/

The default page contains everything you will need to get up and running and in what order:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

If it is still not working after you put this in your page then something else is going on.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Yes it seems something else is going on

Comment: I added below code and it is still not working. But this code is working on  http://dojo.telerik.com/ <div id="calendar"></div>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#calendar").kendoCalendar();
        });

Comment: I got it. It is something related to my _layout.cshtml. It works once I added @{
    Layout =null;
} on top of the view

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the following line in _layout.cshtml page 
    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")*@
and add the below lines at the end of the head section :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.903/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```